# Iterate over links' array with Capybara

Tags: ruby, capybara

I'm trying to take a screenshot of the last three links found on a menu of a page.

```
all('.menu-left a').last(3).each do |e|
  txt = e.text
  puts txt

  e.click
  puts "clicked!"
  page.save_screenshot(txt + ".png")
  page.evaluate_script('window.history.back()')
end
```

Unfortunately I get:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/capybara-webkit-1.0.0/lib/capybara/webkit/node.rb:132:in `invoke': Capybara::Webkit::NodeNotAttachedError (Capybara::Webkit::NodeNotAttachedError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/capybara-webkit-1.0.0/lib/capybara/webkit/node.rb:4:in `visible_text'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/capybara-2.2.0/lib/capybara/node/element.rb:61:in `block in text'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/capybara-2.2.0/lib/capybara/node/base.rb:81:in `synchronize'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/capybara-2.2.0/lib/capybara/node/element.rb:57:in `text'
```

How can I iterate over the links' array, click on it, take the screenshot, go back and repeat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By clicking a link (causing page change), the references to the elements become invalid.

Save the `href` attributes somewhere and visit them instead of clicking elements. (If the elements are `a` tags).

If the clicking elements cause javascript code executed, you need to re-evaluate the css selectors to get elements again.